# Translation for "Burst"/"Bursting" (neuroscience)

Tags: перевод

Direct translation as "Взрыв" sounds extremely wrong when talking about neural bursting. Some neurons can fire a number of spikes (burst of spikes) in a short period of time, followed by a period of quiescence. This phenomenon is called bursting. I have trouble finding a proper translation for the term.

**UPD**: thanks for the suggestions. I'll try to resolve the confusion. I'm referring to a specific dynamical regime of a *single* neuron, which happens to be called "bursting", as described here: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bursting. It's different from the notion of an abstract abrupt increase in the (possibly collective) neural activity, which, I agree, can be nicely translated as "всплеск"/"вспышка".

Comment: It's "всплеск".

Comment: Thanks. Can you point to any sources that use this translation? I couldn't find any. And "всплеск" sounds a little like an abrupt increase in some graded quantity, not in the frequency of discreet events. I was thinking about something on the lines of "пакет".

Comment: btw, Ukrainian translation is even more welcome

Comment: Очередь? As in "a burst from a machine gun"?

Comment: "Вспышка" like in `вспышка заболеваемости` - something big increase in a short period of time.

Comment: На украинском "всплеск" - это "сплеск", а "вспышка" - это "спалах".

Comment: @Dima, sounds tempting. I couldn't find any sources though. It looks like all Russian neuroscientists write only in English.

Comment: @dmytro, in that case you get to coin your own term. :)

Comment: В электротехнике это называется _импульсной посылкой_ или _серией импульсов_. And in English -- the corresponding terms in electrical engineering are _импульсная посылка_ or _серия импульсов_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPD**: Proper equivalent for "bursting neuron" in Russian neuroscience is `залповый нейрон` ([see here](http://biology_en_ru.academic.ru/9754/bursting_neuron)). It seems weird for me, but google finds some examples of such collocation.

---

Here is some examples that use `Всплеск` in the sense of "neuron activity burst":

> **Всплеск** нейронной активности, как причина ярких «предсмертных видений» [[1]](http://med36.com/new/593)
>
> Более того, у активных мышей мозг проявлял все признаки контроля над
>   реакциями, поскольку был зарегистрирован **всплеск** активности так
>   называемых тормозящих нейронов, которые отвечают за контроль над легко
>   возбудимыми нейронами, а также нейроны у этих мышей вырабатывали
>   большее количество нейромедиатора гамма-аминомасляной кислоты (GABA),
>   которая также снижает возбудимость нейронов. [[2]](http://detalimira.com/news/1722/)
>
> В ходе односекундного пения отдельные нейроны в HVC запускают лишь
>   один короткий **всплеск** активности в определенной точке времени пения. [[3]](http://sbio.info/page.php?al=nejrony_rabotajut_po_pri)

The word `Вспышка` is acceptable too:

> Так вот, при приступах катаплексии, как и в парадоксальном сне, у
>   собак отмечались мощные **вспышки** активности этих нейронов! [[4]](http://vivovoco.rsl.ru/VV/JOURNAL/NATURE/11_05/SLEEP.HTM)

Comment: Thanks. The only thing that bugs me is that all the examples above refer to an abstract burst in *collective* neuronal activity. It is valid in some sense, but doesn't point directly to the distinct, periodic dynamical regime of a *single* neuron, called "Bursting" (like described here: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Bursting). I'm gonna give this question another day or two and accept your answer if nothing more suitable pops up.